# Unable to create a new remote session when trying to launch calculator via windows application driver

Tags: selenium, appium, windows-application-driver

I am trying to launch the calculator via windows application driver with below versions

**Selenium standalone** : 3.141.59
**Java Client** : 7.2.0
**Appium** : 1.15.1 (Running on port 127.0.0.1:4723)
**Windows application driver** : running like this WinAppDriver.exe 4727

**Below is my code**

```
package test;

import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.junit.Test;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;

import io.appium.java_client.windows.WindowsDriver;
import io.appium.java_client.windows.WindowsElement;

public class Calculator {

    public static WindowsDriver CalculatorSession;
    public static WindowsElement CalculatorResult;
    public static WebDriver driver;

    @Test
    public void LaunchApp() throws MalformedURLException, InterruptedException {
        DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
        capabilities.setCapability("platformName", "Windows");
        capabilities.setCapability("deviceName", "WindowsPC");
        capabilities.setCapability("app", "c://Windows//System32//calc.exe");
        CalculatorSession = new WindowsDriver<WindowsElement>(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4727"), capabilities);

        System.out.println("driver value" + CalculatorSession);
        CalculatorSession.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

        Thread.sleep(4000);
        CalculatorSession.findElementByName("One").click();
        CalculatorSession.findElementByName("Plus").click();
        CalculatorSession.findElementByName("Seven").click();
        CalculatorSession.findElementByName("Equals").click();
    }

}
```

When I am running the code then calculator opens for 1 time and then below error appears

*org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Unable to create a new remote session. Please check the server log for more details. Original error: Failed to locate opened application window with appId: c://Windows//System32//calc.exe, and processId: 2244 (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 2.30 seconds
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:25:53'*

**I have tried using this path also** : Microsoft.WindowsCalculator_10.1910.0.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe
but its also not working and giving below error

*org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Unable to create a new remote session. Please check the server log for more details. Original error: The system cannot find the file specified (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 652 milliseconds
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:25:53'*

Comment: anyone please help on this

Answer (score 0):

It should be "Microsoft.WindowsCalculator_8wekyb3d8bbwe!App" instead of "c://Windows//System32//calc.exe".

You can find app id's by running powerShell command "get-StartApps"